# Angular: TypeError: interceptors.reduceRight is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call a `PUT` request from my angular app. And I'm receiving the following error: [image]

My Code is given below:

**app.components.ts**

```
import { TestComponent } from "../shared/test/test.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html'
  providers: [ Service  ]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild("testTemplate")
   testTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
   data: string = "";
   constructor( private service:Service ) {}

   updateData({  id, data }) {
      this.service.updateData(id, data)
   }
}
```

**app.components.html**, calling a component.

```
<ng-template #testTemplate>

    <app-test 
      [id]="id"
      [(data)]="data"
      (updateAction)="updateData($event)"></app-test>
</ng-template>
```

**test.components.ts**. After any change to input, parent component update function will called.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  inputs: ["id", "data" ],
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="data" (change)="updateData(data)" />`
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() data: string;
  @Output() updateAction = new EventEmitter();

  updateData(value) {
     this.updateAction.emit({id: this.id, data: value});
  }
}
```

**service.ts**, calling server.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
   header: HttpHeaders;

   constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      this.header = new HttpHeaders()
        .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
   }

   public updateData(id, data) {
     return this.http.put(`${env["api"]}/${id}/update`, { data })    
       .subscribe(result => {  console.log({result});  }, error => {  console.error(error);  })
   }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using HTTP interceptors? What is the relevant code?

Comment: @rveerd I'm not using `HTTP interceptors`, I also tried, but no result

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660201/11248062
Using service in HTTP interceptor which has HttpClient dependency, you will get cyclic dependency error. Using Injector in intercept will solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

Experience the same problem, and it was fixed with following

providers: [ {
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass : AuthInterceptor, multi : true
}],

App.Module provider should contain "multi: true" part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are modifying the header. You have added an additional parameter "authorization". You probably have a library that uses "HTTP Inteceptors" and that additional parameter produces the error.

I have the same error for using "ngx-cookie-service". Replacing this library with another with the same functionality solves this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this on your service or add it into your providers:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```