# Angular project throws cyclic dependancy, but works on other machines

Tags: angular

I have an angular project which has been working for the past couple days, but out of no where started throwing a cyclic dependancy error when visiting any page other than homepage. 
**Error: "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! UserService"** 
There is also another error which shows on every page: **"Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS"**. 
I am running this code on an apple M1 chip (not sure if that's relavent). The entire project works perfectly on AWS Amplify and on an older MacBook. I have tried removing angular and reinstalling, checking versions and resetting the entire project but the error persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660044/cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-http-interceptors-error-in-ngmod/51660201

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! HTTP\_INTERCEPTORS ("\[ERROR ->\]"): in NgModule CoreModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660044/cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-http-interceptors-error-in-ngmod)

Answer (score 0):

A simple clear of browser cache fixed it :)